# react+django questions about https(SSL certificate)

Tags: reactjs, django, ssl, https

I created a website using react and django. React was used as a front-end, Django was used as a back-end.(React uses S3, and Django uses EC2 server.)
I was asked to adapt the website to HTTPS. I know I need to use SSL certificate. However, the front-page running on S3 can use and SSL certificate, so HTTPS is applicable, but the server running on EC2 can't use an SSL certificate. Because EC2 uses IP address, not useing Domain address.
There are times when I need to make an API call to "http://my_ip_address/~" on the my website, but it keeps getting blocked.

Please help me. How should I solve it?
Do I need to add another Domain address to the EC2 server......? Or Is there a way to make a request from HTTPS to HTTP using CORS? I really need your help....!

I applied SSL certificate to S3(front-page). But EC2 server is still HTTP.

Django "settings.py" file :
...
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
...

I also applied the above settings.